# JQuery split by selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I would like to know if there is a method for splitting a jQuery object into multiple parts (based on a selector), but not using the base javascript `split();` method, which would only work on a string.

I'd want to be able to do something like: `$("body").splitBySelector("br").each();` etc etc...

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>More text</p>
        <br />
        <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
        <p>Some other text</p>
        <br class="atrivialexample"/>
        <p>Yet more text</p>
        <p>and another</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But as you can see if I were to use the `split();` function I would not be able to account for any classes or ids or any other attributes that may or may not be present in the markup. And I would not be returned jquery objects,so I could continue chaining.

The simpler the solution the better.

Comment: What do you expect to be doing with these multiple parts? Does each new jQuery collection object get stored somewhere?

Comment: I dont want the `<br/>`s returned I want the html that they delimit, and separated by that delimitation, make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your HTML should look like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="block1">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>More text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="block2">
            <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
            <p>Some other text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="block3">
            <p>Yet more text</p>
            <p>and another</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then, well, you know what to do.

Otherwise, if you insist, `.nextUntil` may be of [use](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to you. The example on the documentation page there looks very similar to what you're asking about.

Comment: Yeah it would help if the markup was something I could control, but for the puposes of this question I cant and have to achive this using javascript, i'm looking into `.nextUntil` (never heard of it before), then I'll get back to checking the answers.

Comment: yes. thank you `.nextUntil` is exaclty what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do (because I can't see this as being all that useful IRL), you could use split.

```
var html = $("body").html().split(/<br[^>]?>/gi);
for(var i = 0; i < html.length; i++){
    // $(html[i]) etc.
}
```

It's not real useful because the jQuery object created there in the for loop doesn't have any relationship to what's on the page aside from being a copy...